# Java inline interface implementation, variables and method calls

Tags: java, java-8

In Java, why can I do this

```
new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
        screenClosed();
    }
}

// ...

public void screenClosed() {
    running = false;
}
```

but not

```
new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
        running = false;
    }
}
```

?

Comment: looks like Java rules and thats it. screenClosed() logically though - makes sense like it is

Comment: What is `running` and where is it defined?

Comment: It's only because screenClosed is declared public. If running was public, that would work too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that `running` is a local variable, not a field in your second example, and you have to make it a field with the `screenClosed` method to make it work? It's hard to tell from your code sample.

If so: inner classes such as local or anonymous classes require that (local) variables are marked `final` (they are constants). This is due to the way the compiler constructs the class by passing the variable as an argument to the compiler-created constructor, and then storing it as a field in the compiler-generated class.

You can get around this limitation by declaring the local variable as:

```
final boolean[] running = new boolean[]{true};
```

and then setting `running[0] = false` instead.